# Jquery listener for change of element id

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to set up a listener to fire when an elements id changes, I don't know if this is possible but here is my attempt (that isn't working).

```
$(".appSelect").on('change', function() {
   //fire change event
});
```

maybe something like :

```
$(".appSelect").attr("id").on('change', function() {
```

Is this possible in jquery?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not possible with a listener because no event occurs. You'd have to periodically check the ID with a `setInterval` function or similar. Better, tie into the function that changes the ID with a callback.